# How to DEBUG log only specific statements from a spring-framework class?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I want spring to only log the following code line:

`this.logger.debug("New connection " + this.getConnectionId());`

Therefore I added the following configuration in `application.properties`:
`logging.level.org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection=DEBUG`

This works fine, but of course it logs any `logger.debug()` statements from that class.

Question: is it possible to log only the desired statement?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it listening to socket events instead:

```
@Component
public class SocketListener {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @EventListener
    public void onTcpConnectionOpenEvent(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("new con " + event.getConnectionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onTcpConnectionCloseEvent(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("con closed " + event.getConnectionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onTcpConnectionOpenEvent(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event) {
        LOGGER. error("con error " + event.getConnectionId());
    }
}
```